# how to dump console log in file

Tags: java, android, logging

In my java project I am using apache log4j-1.2.17.jar  for storing logs in file  and manually  uploading these file Logs to server for future ref , Is there any other Logging tool or library is available which collect and send log to a webservice periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took help from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm and change in appender.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious approach would be to write your own `PeriodicallyUploadsToServerAppender` rather than using the standard `FileAppender` - you could even have it extend the FileAppender and get the best of both worlds.

Another simpler approach - especially if you're on a unix/linux platform - is to use `cron` to `logrotate` the logs and at the same time send them to your server.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You can write custom appender using log4j APIs and can be used to log.

```
public class CustomAppender extends AppenderSkeleton implements Appender {
   protected void append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent) {
    // business logic to send logs to external system/exposed services
   }

   public void close() {

   }

   public boolean requiresLayout() {
        return false;
   }
}
```